# I need to build an array of arrays, having trouble conceptualizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I'm trying to collect values for Chart.js that takes this array

```
data = [{ value:1, color:#123456 }]
```

HTML:

```
<table class="card">
    <tr class="section1">
        <td class="label">One</td>
        <td class="goal">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section2">
        <td class="label">Two</td>
        <td class="goal">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section3">
        <td class="label">Three</td>
        <td class="goal">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section4">
        <td class="label">Four</td>
        <td class="goal">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section5">
        <td class="label">Five</td>
        <td class="goal">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section6">
        <td class="label">Six</td>
        <td class="goal">6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.card tr.section1 td.label{
    color: #c26558;
}
table.card tr.section2 td.label{
    color: #cdaf76;
}
table.card tr.section3 td.label{
    color: #6e9874;
}
table.card tr.section4 td.label{
    color: #809ead;
}
table.card tr.section5 td.label{
    color: #467082;
}
table.card tr.section6 td.label{
    color: #ac9578;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var data = []; //{ value: 30, color:"#F38630" },
var goals = document.getElementsByTagName( $('table.card .goal').html() );
var quantities = jQuery.makeArray( goals );

for( var i=0; i<quantities.length; i++ ){
    var labelColor = '#000000';

    $('table.card .goal').each(function(){
        if( $(this).html() == quantities[i] ){
            labelColor = rgb2hex( $(this).closest('tr').find('.label').css('color') );
        }
    });

    data[i] = { 'value':quantities[i], 'color':labelColor };
}
```

This is my latest attempt at making an array of quantities to work with.  I was fiddling with jQuery.toArray() before makeArray().  I don't know, maybe my entire approach is off.  The chunk that grabs the css('color') is working, I'm pretty happy with that, but I am having a hard time turning the values of the .goal cells into an array.

Here's the Chart.js documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName( $('table.card .goal').html() );` Do you  understand what `getElementsByTagName()` does?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, this was my latest attempt, I was grabbing at straws by adding the html().  Thanks though, that was

Comment: discouraging, man.  I wish I'd noticed I used TagName instead of ClassName an hour ago, let alone before I posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah, I see. You were trying to build a selector, something like `"section" + $('table.card .goal').html()`. Yeah, that would need to be done one at a time. There are complex selectors that can be used to select based on the start of an attribute, like `$("tr[class^=section]");` to grab all `tr` elements where the `class` attribute starts with `"section"`.

Comment: Now we're cookin', cookie monster.  That explains why when I alerted quantities.length it was always 1!

Comment: See the [selectors category](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of the jQuery API for more selector information. Some are valid native selectors for use with the native `querySelector/querySelectorAll` methods. And others are specific to jQuery's selector engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made it much more complicated than need be. Just select the `td.goal` elements, and use `.map()` to return an object to a new array with the values from the current goal.

```
var result = $("table.card tr[class^=section] td.goal").map(function(i, tr) {
    var goal = $(this);
    return {
        value: parseInt(goal.text(), 10),
        color:goal.prev().css('color') || '#000000'
    };
}).toArray();
```

Comment: Nice, this map function is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!

Comment: Important addition for posterity, the text() function isn't recognized as a number, so you have to wrap the return like so:

    return {value: parseInt(goal.text()), color:goal.prev().css('color') || '#000000'}

p.s. I love the '|| black' on the end of the return, very elegant solution.

Comment: @NominalAeon: Good point. I neglected the conversion. Will update to be thorough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ReuUG/)</kbd>

```
var data = $('.card tr').map(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    return {
        value: $this.find('.goal').text(),
        color: $this.find('.label').css('color') //will return like "rgb(194, 101, 88)"
    }
}).get();
console.log(data);
```